# Problem with creating a PV-ubuntu-guest with Xen on slackware

Tags: virtualization, xen

I don't know if I'm in the right place but:
i have Xen installed on slackware and i wanted to create an Ubuntu-Guest-Domain.
I created the xen-config-file(attached) manually and created a new guest domain; i use vncviewer to display the graphical interface of ubuntu and tried to install it the normal way;
problem is i got stucked right after the point where i must erase my disk etc.. erorr message also attached
i created a new partition with the command:

```
sudo lvcreate -L 40G -n ubuntu-database /dev/vg0
```

but i dont now how i join them with my config file :(

Error message in ubuntu:[errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQGb1.png)

configfile section DISK:

```
disk = [
'tap:aio:/net/p2fnas/data/xenimages/ubuntu-18.04.1_400G.img,xvda1,w',
'drbd:r0,xvda1,w',
'file:/net/p2fnas/data/xenimages/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r'
]
```

Hopefully someone can help me out of this trouble

kind regards dfresh

Answer (score 0):

Nachtrag ich habe mich jetzt genau nach dieser [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) gehalten und jetzt funktioniert es prinzipell...

Jedoch habe ich jetzt ein weiteres Problem:
Nachdem alles fertig installiert ist änderte ich die Bootreihenfolge in meiner config und nach erneutem hochfahren sieht meine Ubuntu so aus:
[bild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULBXv.png)

Answer (score 0):

ich habe jetzt mal anstatt der Desktopveriosn eine Serverversion benutzt..
Weiß jemand wiso meine adresse nicht im subnetz sein soll?

[network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLpPy.png)